# Can I get MatLab to not call functions in a specific directory?

Tags: matlab

## A little background

I'm working on a project that requires me to use an old (from 2006) large system of MatLab scripts. The script exists in an archive folder on a cluster but I need it to run fully from my cluster folder. I've got it mostly running from my personal folder but not entirely. It runs perfectly but there is a Python script that is called somewhere that doesn't exist in my personal directory.

## What I want to do

Since the MatLab code I'm running includes many different script files, which themselves call even more script files, poring through them to find information about the Python script would be very very time consuming.

Therefore, I would like to be able to tell MatLab to not go to specific folders when calling a script, but instead, return an error. For example, if a scripted is called in the directory `/notmyfolder`, I want it to return an error.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are the scripts called? Did you put the subfolders on the path? Matlab shouldn't find scripts that are in subfolders not on the path.
Also, can you deduce information about the missing python script from any error message? If you know the file name, you could do a recursive search for it (outside MATLAB).

Comment: They are called throughout. So, I call a script by passing an options file to it. The options file contains many variables. The main script parses this an then begins calling a wide array of other scripts depending on the variables is reads. These other scripts are rather long (1000's) of lines and buried somewhere inside them many other scripts are then called. Because of this, I'm unable to find where the Python script is run. Since the code runs fine, I don't get any errors.  But I can't delete the Python script from it's current location due to permissions so I can't force an error.

Comment: Are the scripts called by their name only? Then they have to be on the path to be found, so removing the folder containing them form the path will cloak them from MATLAB. However, if they're called using `run`, then that might include the path.
Are there many python scripts being called? You can use a tool like `grep` to recursively search your MATLAB scripts for '`.py`' which would be a good indicator for a Python script to single out the call.

Comment: Some of the scripts are called by their name only but some are not. The path doesn't include any folders outside my personal folder so the python script is being called by not using path. I'll try grep.